# Remote control the mouse or touch screen of android devices

Tags: android, events, mouse, screen

Is there any way to create a background service (or driver or anything else) can control the mouse or keyboard or touch screen event of the android? I saw there was some remote controlled android TV, so how did they achieve that which is using remote controller to show mouse cursor and others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is specific to Google TV. Mouse events are faked. Check out the [Anymote Protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/#mouseevents) for details on how to remotely control your GTV device.

It's also discussed a bit in [this GTV doc](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/static/presofiles/developing_android_applications_for_google_tv.pdf&ei=kkAWT4mhLILi0QGC4NX3Ag&usg=AFQjCNH16niVhmqKwLII5J1ZjEJ1tKCvlA).

Comment: Thank you dhaag23, I found that they actually "BTN_*" to the keyevent to generate the mouse event, which are not in the standard android os(at lease not in my 2.3.3). So may I know how does they modify this? Do they create a virtual mouse driver and name the new IOCTL as "BTN_*"? If that where can I find this part? Maybe I can add this in my android.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a system hack to get this functionality.

What I do know is that Android provides a Instrumentation class that will allow an application to inject event in toe system.  However, to use this class the application must be a system app stored in /system/app and signed with the platform key from which the Android build came from.  So you either need these keys or build your own Android ROM.  Which means its a system hack :)